# Lisp prefix calculator

Tags: lisp, scheme, prefix

How can I write a calculator to prefix notation, when it should count this example '(+ * 3 2 - 2 1), where there are no brackets between characters? When I have the brackets, I can handle it, but in this case I am lost.

Comment: Hint: this is "Polish notation", algorithms for which can surely be found by some googling.

Comment: Show some effort please.

Comment: Two words: recursive descent.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search on google yielded [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation#Order_of_operations) wikipedia page, with an implementation (in pseudocode) of prefix evaluation using a stack. It's a starting point for writing your own implementation. Also notice that a stack can be easily implemented using Lisp's linked lists, simply add/remove elements at the head.

Comment: "Note that under this implementation the input string is scanned from right to left." -- this is actually an algorithm for suffix (reverse Polish) notation. Not that it matters much, as reversing a list in Scheme is trivial.

Comment: No, the linked algorithm is for a prefix (Polish) expression, but the input is scanned from right to left

Comment: ... so the order of arguments is reversed. Right. (I was bored and just implemented the OP's homework. Turns out I still know enough Scheme :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner in scheme (excuse me if it is nasty code). This one is with the brackets:

```
(define (fce a)
  (case a
    (( + ) +)
    (( - ) -)
    (( * ) *)
    (( / ) /)))

(define (analyze vyraz)
  (if (list? vyraz)
      (calcul vyraz)
      vyraz))

(define (calcul vyraz)
  (if (= (length vyraz) 3 )
      ((fce (car vyraz)) (analyze (cadr vyraz)) (analyze (caddr vyraz)))
      (calcul (cons (calcul (list (car vyraz) (cadr vyraz) (caddr vyraz) (cadddr vyraz)))))))
```

this code can count for example this : `(calcul '(- (* 3 2)(+ 1 2))`

I wanted to repair this code to code without brackets but conditions and listing the original input stopped me. I do not know how to write the conditions so that I didn't lose the original input and also came the final calculation.

there are my conditions (but i think, there are at wrong syntax

```
(define (count vyraz)
  (cond (list? vyraz)
        (number? (car vyraz) (cons (car vyraz)))
        (number? (cdr vyraz) (cons (cdr vyraz)))
        (symbol? (cddr vyraz) (cons (cddr vyraz)))
        (else (cdr vyraz) (count vyraz))) 
  (calcul vyraz))
```

Thank you for all your answers and tips :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (polish-notation-eval expr)
 (if (finished? expr) 
     (car expr)
     (polish-notation-eval (the-once-over expr))))
```

;;either we are finished, or we need to make the-once-over to get closer to finished.

```
(define (the-once-over expr)
  (cond ((null? expr) expr )
    ((well-formed-expr? expr)
     (cons ((get-operator (car expr)) (cadr expr) (caddr expr))
           (the-once-over (cdddr expr))))
    (else (cons (car expr) (the-once-over (cdr expr))))))
```

;; just scrolls down the list looking for well-formed expressions to evaluate.

```
(define *the-operations*
  (list (list '+ +)
    (list '* *)
    (list '- -)
    (list '/ /)))
```

;; an association list with names and functions

```
(define (get-operator name)
  (cadr (assoc name *the-operations*)))
```

;;returns the function that goes with the name

```
(define (finished? expr) 
 (= (length expr) 1))
```

;; we are finished one we get down to a length one list, otherwise not

```
(define (well-formed-expr? expr)
 (and (assoc (car expr) *the-operations*) 
      (number? (cadr expr))
      (number? (caddr expr))))
 ;;are the next three elements something we can go ahead and evaluate?
```